# FLTK's Fl_Scroll - run code in reaction to scrolling happening?

Tags: fltk

I am using [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/) 1.3, displaying a single Flex column with a number of Flex rows inside a Fl_Scroll. I want to do something to rows that were outside of the visible area when they scroll into view. But I cannot figure out how to do that. There is no event emitted when the scroll position changes (as far as I can see) nor does a callback on the scroll seem to do anything.

The only solution I can think of is something like using the column's, scroll's, or window's `callback` to get informed of all UI events (such as move, key up, leave, ..) and use them to check whether the scoll's `yposition` has changed from the last time and run the code I need if it is....

But there surely must be a better way?

Thank you!!!

Comment: This is a very interesting question. You seem to be right that there's no callback of the Fl_Scroll defined. We (the FLTK devs; I'm one of them) could maybe add one that is fired when the scroll position (x and/or y) is changed. I suggest to open a thread in our official development forum (Google Group) fltk.coredev (https://groups.google.com/g/fltkcoredev) to discusse this. Another option would be to ask for help in fltk.general (https://groups.google.com/g/fltkgeneral) where user questions can be asked. Maybe someone has a better idea.

Comment: A really hackish idea is to intercept the Fl_Scrollbar callbacks (one or both) but this is unsupported and you really need to know what you do. I don't recommend this! Anyway, this is an untested recipe: the Fl_Scroll widget defines two callback functions, one for each scrollbar, in its constructor. You can query these callbacks with Fl_Scrollbar::callback(), save the address(es), and then assign your own callback(s). In your own callback you first call the saved callback and then do your own stuff. Maybe this could work - but I would only try it for test code! See my previous comment.

Comment: Third idea: derive your own class from Fl_Scroll, implement the handle() method, figure out whether an event goes to one of the scrollbars, and if yes, let Fl_Scroll handle it and then do your own stuff. Fl::event_inside() can tell you whether an event applies to a particular widget (scrollbar or hscrollbar). You can save the result, call Fl_Scroll::handle() *always*, then use the saved result. Or, even simpler, check the scrollbar positions after Fl_Scroll::handle() etc.. However, this will not catch resize() op's, so you will have to override resize() as well. Just some thoughts...

Comment: I ended up checking the scroll's yposition every ± 100ms (the lowest granularity) - as can be seen in https://github.com/holyjak/img-mg/blob/8a188a1998bab10aff5a1e7d286b9444d426ba17/src/main.rs#L117

Comment: Thanks a lot, Albrecht! I I will go to the fora.

Comment: @AlbrechtSchlosser interesting questions should be upvoted. :)